# Parse Lower Line in For Loop

Tags: python, csv

I'm tyring to take an inputted list of IP's and their corresponding ticket number and turn it into a csv. The ticket(s) for each IP is located on the line below the IP on the list, so how could I read an IP, parse the ticket number below it, and print both those values out in CSV format?

My code and list of IP's/Tix #'s are below.

```
m = re.search(r'(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}(-\d{2}|slash\d{2})?',item, re.M|re.I)
n = re.search(r'10A-\d{6}',item, re.M|re.I)
for line in fiEsccb:
    if m in line:
        #go to below line and extract n (possibly multiple)
        print m + ',' + n
```

List

```
8.8.8.8
Open Menu  10A-002671 10/21/2016

8.8.8.8
10A-003079  

8.8.8.8
10A-003179 10A-003178 10A-003172 10A-003171 10A-003170   

8.8.8.8   
10A-002970  

8.8.8.8
10A-002970
```

Comment: post what output you want as a sample at least

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is a regular list of strings, as shown in your example, you can group it into a list of tuples of three using `itertools`:

```
import itertools
data = ['8.8.8.8', 'Open Menu  10A-002671 10/21/2016', '', '8.8.8.8', '10A-003079', '', '8.8.8.8', '10A-003179 10A-003178 10A-003172 10A-003171 10A-003170', ''] # Add more lines

args=[iter(data)]*3
collected = list(itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=''))
print(collected)
# [('8.8.8.8', 'Open Menu  10A-002671 10/21/2016', ''), ('8.8.8.8', '10A-003079', ''), ('8.8.8.8', '10A-003179 10A-003178 10A-003172 10A-003171 10A-003170', '')]
```

This list can be easily saved as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `while True` loop and `readline()` as such:

```
while True:
    line1 = fiEsccb.readline()
    if m in line1:
         line2 = fiEsccb.readline()
         if n in line2:
             print m + ',' + line2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex as below to generate a list from the data from the input ip texfile and then writhe into a csv:

```
import csv,re

ippattern = r'\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}'
packetpattern = r'10A-\d{6}'
data = []

with open(r"C:\ipinfo.txt", 'rb') as ipfile:
    lines = ipfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(ippattern,line):
            ip = re.findall(ippattern,line)[0]
            packet = re.findall(packetpattern,lines[lines.index(line)+1])[0]
            data.append([ip,packet])
with open(r"C:\ipinfo_output.csv", 'wb') as ipout:
    writer = csv.writer(ipout)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Output csv:

```
8.8.8.8,10A-002671
8.8.8.8,10A-002671
8.8.8.8,10A-002671
8.8.8.8,10A-002970
8.8.8.8,10A-002671
```

This approach generates several duplicates which are unnecessary I think. To avoid this you can use dictionary where ip is dictionary key and packet is the dictionary value.Then write this dictionary into a csv file.

Or you can import this duplicate csv file into excel and remove duplicates by one command `remove duplicates` in the microsoft excel in the `Data` tab.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you have to apply the regex for IPs for whole lines and the regex for ticket numbers for items on the following lines:

```
import re
reIP = r'(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}(-\d{2}|slash\d{2})?'
reTicketNr = r'10A-\d{6}'
for line in fiEsccb:
  line = line.strip()
  if line == '': continue
  mg = re.match(reIP,line)
  if mg:
    ip = mg.group(0)
  else:
    possibleTicketNrs = line.split()
    for item in possibleTicketNrs:
      if re.match(reTicketNr,item):
        print(','.join([ip,item]))
```

With

```
fiEsccb = ['8.8.8.8', 'Open Menu  10A-002671 10/21/2016', '', '8.8.8.8', '10A-003079', '', '8.8.8.8', '10A-003179 10A-003178 10A-003172 10A-003171 10A-003170', '']
```

you will get:

```
8.8.8.8,10A-002671
8.8.8.8,10A-003079
8.8.8.8,10A-003179
8.8.8.8,10A-003178
8.8.8.8,10A-003172
8.8.8.8,10A-003171
8.8.8.8,10A-003170
```